# LiveData observer's onchanged() method executes several times

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I am new to the android development. Currently i am working with the architecture components. When I inflate my fragment for the first time the Observer onChanged() executed several times so the data in my ui got repeated. But it is working fine when I detach and attach the fragment.

**MyFragment.java**

```
private MyViewModel myViewModel;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
 container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
             return rootView;
    }


   @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MealViewModel.class);
        myViewModel.getBreakfast(randomNum).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new    Observer<List<BreakFast>>() {

                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<BreakFast> breakFasts) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < breakFasts.size(); i++) {
                        String food = breakFasts.get(i).getFood();
                        if (food.contains("||")) {
                            food = food.replace("||", "\n");
                        }
                        builder.append( food + "\n");
                    }
                    resultTextView.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            });
}
```

In the above code, the onChanged method gets executed many times when the view inflates for the first time.

Comment: Could you share some of the code? but if it runs multiple times, it may be because you are subscribing several times. It would be nice if you can share some code to see where your problem may be

Comment: @JuanE.LondoñoT. I have added the piece of code.can you help me to sort this out.

Comment: In the code that you share, it's fine, since what you do there is that you subscribe to the changes that happen in myViewModel.getBreakfast (randomNum), where some problem may be happening is when notifying the changes of `myViewModel.getBreakfast(randomNum)`.

Comment: check in to ViewModel how many times the changes are being notified

Comment: According to Docs onActivityCreated will be Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle). Try moving it to another callback like OnViewCreated.

Answer (score 0):

LiveData is a type of observable. Its job is to publish changes when data hosted in it gets updated (either manually by calling postValue on it or automatically when new data is added)

If you want to get data only once, then LiveData is not an option for you. You can simply use [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html)  to achieve this.

Another thing that you can do is - simply ignore changes when they are pushed to you second time onward through your onChanged() method. What I mean by this is, do not update your text view second time onward. However, you should really have a separation logic that's clean enough to distinguish in between the callback that you will use and other callbacks that you won't use.

One last thing that I can think of is remove observer - your current lifecycle owner (activity or fragment) once you have observed the changes once. By calling removeObserver() method on LiveData.

**PS: All of these are just workarounds. You should really rethink about using LiveData if live changes to the data is not something that you wanted to begin with.**